# Serializing AspNet.Identity objects from a WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm at the verge of going insane with this one, so here goes...

I've separated the tightly-coupled login/user management system from MVC5 and stuck this in my own User Management service, which works great when referencing the service through a DLL (just for testing). However, when it comes to proper SOA and referencing this service I get:

```
Type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserLoginInfo' cannot be serialized
```

Brilliant. So I've gone around trying my damnest to get rid of the serialization errors of other objects, but stuck on this one.

Here's the only place it's used:

```
 public LoginResult AddLogin(string userId, LoginInfo info)
 {
     var createdUser = UserManager.AddLogin(userId, new UserLoginInfo(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey));

     return new LoginResult
     {
         Errors = createdUser.Errors.ToList(),
         Succeeded = createdUser.Succeeded
     };
```

As you can see, I can't get around not using it, but I'm not passing it between the Service -> Client, so I've got no idea why the compiler is wanting to Serialize it anyway.

I've tried:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserLoginInfo))]
```

on my service and no luck also. I can't even add a `[DataContract]` as it's part of another library, or make a new object and inherit from `UserLoginInfo` as `AddLogin` requires that object.

Surely there has to be a solution for this?

*Edit*

My transformation classes as requested:

```
namespace UserManagement.Core.Service
{
    [DataContract]
    public class LoginResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class LoginInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ProviderKey { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    // Removed
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.3" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.3"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

SVC markup:

```
namespace UserManagement.Core.Service
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public partial class UserManagementService : IUserManagementService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _factory;

        UnitOfWork<ApplicationDbContext> _context;

        /// <summary>
        /// AssociationService Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="factory"></param>
        public UserManagementService(IUnitOfWorkFactory<ApplicationDbContext> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;

            // Use the context sent from the web application
            if (OperationContext.Current != null)
            {
                string dbContextName = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>("DatabaseContext", "");
                _context = this._factory.Create(dbContextName);
            }
            else
            {
                _context = this._factory.Create();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the `LoginResult` class, is that your class?

Comment: and LoginInfo, who's class is that?

Comment: Yep, LoginResult is my own class so I could bypass serialization issues with another AspNet.Identity class. I'll post that here, but not 100% sure why that would interfere with UserLoginInfo.

Comment: Added those in the question edit.

Comment: Did you add this `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(UserLoginInfo))]` before or after the error?  I would remove it...

Comment: and nothing in your web.config references that class?  (guessing..)

Comment: I added that after the error, then it still had the error, so removed it again. I've just never seen something so "locked down" in the .NET framework - .AddLogin shouldn't take a class that's not Serializable.

Comment: i do WCF all day long, never had any issue like this...  post your contracts, what about the client side?  Are you using your own generated wcf client side classes or the Service Generated classes?

Comment: This is an error I'm getting when visiting the Service (the .svc file when built) directly, so it takes the Client out of the equation. I'm the same, never hit an issue like this!

Comment: post your web.config, you sure your config is the pointing to this same service class?

Comment: Just added the service config - can't see any blinding errors in there at first glance!

Comment: so your just using basicHttp, ok so now post your .svc markup

Comment: Done - all my other services work with the exact same code, it's just this one doesn't work due to that damn object :(

Comment: that's not the .svc markup

Comment: the .svc file would just have a single line pointing to the implementation of the Service contract, also that code you posted doesn't appear to implement your Login methods... what am I missing?